# How can I import other jupyter notebooks into my currently running jupyter notebook in google colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm using jupyter notebook to train neural networks. For cleanliness, I have separated my data processing, model training and model analysis into different notebooks. I was using the command `%run CondensedModelsForMergedDataset.ipynb` to run other notebooks to then use their functions in my currently running notebook.

However, I wanted to increase the size of my neural networks and now their training time is taking too long on my laptop. Google Colab is a great tool for this but I don't know how to, or even if I can, use multiple notebook's functions in my currently running notebook.

I tried the code:

```
!pip install import_ipynb
import import_ipynb
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Add the directory containing your notebook to the system path
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Final Report Resources/')

# Import your notebook as a module
import CondensedModelsForMergedDataset
```

However the code does not recognise `CondensedModelsForMergedDataset` as a valid module.

I would be very grateful for any advice more experienced users would have on this topic.

Comment: Your %run way doesn't work in Colab? That import_ipynb hasn't been updated in five years. Maybe try importnb, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez). Minor quibble: It should be `%pip install import_ipynb` in your code block. The magic install commands were added in 2019 to avoid issues that can arise when using exclamation point in conjunction with install commands in a running Jupyter `.ipynb` file. Google Colab now uses it and so it would be best with the magic variation to encourage others to use best practices.

Comment: Yes it wasn't recognising it, I'm getting more success currently using: %cd "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks" first. I believe the issue was with the project not seeing other projects in the same directory initially.